# Space filling vs D,A,I,etc-optimal experiment design

Tags: experiment-design

What are some of the criteria for choosing one family over the other of experiment design methods ? How does this choice relate to the model of the response ?

I left factorial / fractional factorial out of the title because I see them as special cases of optimal experiment design when the number of runs/candidate points ratio is high. Am I correct ?

I'm specially interested in the following context:

More than 10, all fixed, multi level factors (i.e. categorical variables, with different number of categories), with constraints in some treatments.

Comment: Well, you will aso need to tell us what is thebgoal of this experiments

Comment: These are numerical experiments (with non deterministic results), the goal is the comparison of different algorithms, and identification of the factors affecting performance.

Comment: How costly are each run? Can you explain some of the factors? How large variance? ...  Search this site for surrogate models or response surface models, for instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32322/uncertainty-and-sensitivity-analysis/32442#32442